# WebdriverIO upgrade

Tags: automated-tests, webdriver-io

I have a question. when we are trying to upgrade from webdriverIO 5 to webdriverIO 7;  is there a way to programmatically convert sync calls to async calls?

Any articles that worked you can send it my way or let me know how to do this please. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a codemod that will help you: [WebdriverIO upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74140572/webdriverio-upgrade)

Here is the codemod on github: https://github.com/webdriverio/codemod